# How to delete part of a text string from the values of another column?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a table of 7,000 products from which I need to remove the product id. Id is located at the end of the title, but its length varies

**id_____________Title**

2469005501_____B250 Tow Control Module 2469005501

1321400012_____Egr Valve Combi Valve Pipe 1321400012

6954722________Ignition Switch and Key Gas - 6954722

I tried several formulas that I found here but none of them helped me. How can I do it? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can use [this](https://superuser.com/questions/680769/i-need-to-find-the-last-space-in-a-xls-cell) solution to find the position of the last space in your text. Then you simply combine it with `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-last_space_position)` formula.

Comment: Not all products have an id in the title. Using your solution, part of the title can be cropped. Sorry for not mentioning this right away.

Comment: Ahh fair point - so it looks like you need to look for the first occurrence of "_" character. Try using `=LEFT(A1,FIND("_",A1)-1)`

Comment: With a small modification, your solution worked for me! Thanks

Comment: You're most welcome. I'll post this solution as an answer so that you can close the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the commentary section, you need to look for the first occurrence of "_" character. Try using:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("_",A1)-1)
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this formula.replace '@' symbol to another which you want.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT("@",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)),"@","")
```